# Node.js client.emit only working after first try?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am writing an app where I have a user login via an email and password.  I have my node.js server return either a 'yes' or 'no' if the login is correct.

On the server, I can console.log the result and see it every time. However, the client.emit command only works after the first time. AND only if the inputs 'email' and 'password' are identical for both of those times. So the alert on the client is only firing after the second time.

Here is my server code:

```
client.on('checkcred', function(email, password){
        helper.check(email, password,function(run){
        client.emit('conf',run);
        console.log(run);
                });
        });
```

helper.js

```
exports.check = function(zmail, pasword,callback){

                client.query('SELECT id FROM passwords WHERE email="'+zmail+'"', function(err,data){

                 if(data.length == 0){
                console.log("wrong email");
                callback("no");
                }else{
                        var savedemail = data[0].id;
                        client.query('SELECT password FROM passwords WHERE id='+savedemail+'', function(err,pass){
                                var databasepass = pass[0].password;

                                if (pasword == databasepass){
                                        console.log("correct pass");
                                        callback("yes");
                                }else{
                                        console.log("incorrectpass");
                                        callback("no");
                                }
                        });
                }
     });
                }
```

client

```
 var socket  = io.connect('http://54.213.92.113:8080');

            socket.on('conf', function (yn) {
                      alert(yn);
                      });

 function upload(email, password){

            //check the email and password against the saved email and pass.
            socket.emit('checkcred', email, password);

        }
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You've opened yourself to SQL injection attacks.  Do not concatenate data into a DB query!

Comment: Ok, how should I go about getting the mysql data then? That's the cause of the problem i'm having?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with your problem, but SQL injection attacks are a serious problem. You can read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.  To prevent this, always escape quotes (single and double) in the input.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your socket.on('conf') into a onConnection callback like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('conf', ...)
}
```

Comment: I suggest you leave out all database queries at the server side and just do the `socket.emit('conf', ...)` to see of that works

Comment: It does work. When I move that code outside of the function, it works fine. I think something is going wrong because I have multiple functions within one another?

Comment: No, leave the `client.on` code as is, and change the `exports.check` code to `callback("yes")`. Try this, and see if it works.